# Variable returning pre-defined value due to async function late execution and completion

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code. I am converting blob to base64 here. The reader.onloadend function when called starts processing asynchronously. **So console(reader.result) which should print after the function, prints before the function completion and gives wrong value(value before the change in function).** I want to use the changed value of reader.result after completion of async onload function.

```
        var reader = new window.FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(array); 
        reader.onloadend = kk=function() {
            base64data = reader.result;                
            //console.log(base64data );
            //document.write(base64data);
            //document.getElementById('display1').setAttribute('src',base64data);
            return base64data
            }
            console(reader.result)
```

Comment: Just move the log inside the onloadend handler.

Comment: The commented statements were examples of getting to the data effectively.... why did you put them in comments?

Comment: I am using polymer for web application. This is just an example of usage in console. In actual I want to assign that base64 value to the element in polymer and I cannot assign that while in the function as it gives not defined error due to binding. I need the result out of that function.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to call another method from the onloadend handler:

```
var reader = new window.FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(array); 
        reader.onloadend = kk=function() {
            base64data = reader.result;
            // sync way - execution will start before the rest of the handler
            loadEndCtd(base64data);
            // or async way - execution will start after handler is done
            // setTimeout(function(){ loadEndCtd(base64data); },0);

            return base64data
            }

var loadEndCtd = function( data ){
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Make sure that `base64data` is a local variable

Comment: While initial code strongly suggests this, I've put only changes concerning the question, since the code does not show the declaration of variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just do what you want to do when the result is there, i.e. execute the code that needs the result from within the callback function:

```
var reader = new window.FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(array); 
reader.onloadend = kk= processResult;


function processResult() {
    var base64data = reader.result;
    // all processing should come here or be launched from here.
}
```

Comment: you would need to make sure you return something in that processResult() function, right?

Comment: @James No, you don't `return` anything from asynchronous callbacks unless you're in a promise chain

Comment: Usually it's better to add the load events before reading, just in case the read happens synchronously.